# Why in ie7 , big image cat not cover top all other image?

Tags: html, css, image

Why in ie7 , big image cat not cover top all other image ?

http://jsfiddle.net/8dh8ttsv/
.
.

This is google chrome screenshot
http://image.ohozaa.com/i/2a6/McxR3d.jpg
.
.

And This is IE7 screenshot

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/g01/jFVjdp.jpg

Why in ie7 , big cat image not cover top all other image, how can i do ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html><head></head><body>
    <div style=" width: 94px; height: 94px; float: left; position: relative;">
        <span style="position: absolute; left: 0px; z-index: 999999999;">
            <div style="top: 0px; z-index: 999999999; left: 99px; opacity: 1;">
                <div style="opacity: 1; 
                            position: relative; 
                            z-index: 999; 
                            float: left;">
                    <img src="http://image.ohozaa.com/i/f6f/AJR3oT.png" style=" border: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; ">
                </div>
            </div>        
        </span>
        <span style=" float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
            <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
                <img border="0" src="http://image.ohozaa.com/i/f6f/AJR3oT.png" width="80" height="80">                
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div style=" width: 94px; height: 94px; float: left; position: relative;">
        <span style=" float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
            <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
                <img border="0" src="http://abcfrog.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/pig.png" width="80" height="80">                
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div style=" width: 94px; height: 94px; float: left; position: relative;">
        <span style=" float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
            <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
                <img border="0" src="http://cupcakes123.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/pig-cupcake-v3-200x200.jpg" width="80" height="80">                
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div style=" width: 94px; height: 94px; float: left; position: relative;">
        <span style=" float: left; margin: 7px; width: 80px;">
            <div style=" float: left; height: 80px; ">
                <img border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-tp3UHm_Gb9o/UfXBMZPChnI/AAAAAAAALYs/Q-vb2f32xoM/s200/pig.png" width="80" height="80">                
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    </body></html>
```

Comment: @TheBlueDog is correct. There is CSS that didn't exist then and does exist now, if you were coding 8 years ago you'd know what can and can't be used and create fallbacks, until then you can use caniuse.com and type in opacity to start.

Comment: how to apply for use in ie7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your using the HTML5 DOCTYPE which IE7 doesn't support. The first version of IE that supports HTML5 is Internet Explorer 9.

Your best hope is adding a notice to inform users their browser is out of date, since IE7 is barley used anymore.

Comment: If you crave for IE7 so bad, then you'll have to downgrade your HTML version to something like HTML4. This can be done by changing the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Also, take a look at using a stylesheet inside the head tag.